# Replacing @click.option with @click.argument in Python

Tags: python, click, python-click

I have the following script where I utilize @click.option from the click library in Python. I want to know how to replace it with @click.argument without changing the output.

```
import sys
import click
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
@click.command()

@click.option('--filename')
# @click.argument('result.csv', type=click.Path(exists=True))

def main(filename):

    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    y_test = df["actual"].values
    y_pred = df["predicted"].values

    print('R Squared: ' +  str(metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred)))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv = ['',  '--filename', 'result.csv']
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import click
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
@click.command()

# @click.option('--filename')
## @click.argument('result.csv', type=click.Path(exists=True))
@click.argument('filename', type=click.Path(exists=True))
def main(filename):

    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    y_test = df["actual"].values
    y_pred = df["predicted"].values

    print('R Squared: ' +  str(metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred)))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # sys.argv = ['',  '--filename', 'result.csv']
    sys.argv = ['',  'result.csv']
    main()
```

Comment: I tried the code, it prints out the same output, but with the following error message afterwards : ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module. AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tb_frame'
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemExit: 0

Comment: Anyone has an answer?